# Eclipse Luna - how to collapse / folding javascript private function

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-luna

i use Eclipse Luna JavaEE IDE for Web Developer

How to Collapse javascript private function inside class?

```
  var ClientBattle = function(wtfClient){

        this.setDataPet = function(){
           // code in here can collapse
        }

        function generateBox(){
          // code in here cannot collapse
        }

    }
```

any plugin will also appreciated